# Finding constraint relation between pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

I have to find out the relation between F and M, if rope is pulled with constant velocity V. Please help, these types of multiple pulley messes up my constraint equation. Thanks.
[image: pully]

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: The weight of M is supported by four segments of rope, each with the same tension (assuming you can ignore the mass and friction of the pulleys). The two fixed pulleys on the right have no significant effect.

Answer (score 2):

In constraint relations what I like to is to measure the distance of block and pulleys from the wall above - inertial frame. Next I try to correlate the distances to the length of the string which is constant. This means add or subtract the distances from each other until you get the length of the string .

Further I like to use the fact that all points of a string must have the same acceleration - string is inextensible.

[image]

Note : I am denoting the distance from letters corresponding to the first letter colours shown in figure.

The constraint relation here will be:

b + 2(r-g) + (b-g) y +(y-p) + (w-p) =length of string

Note what I am doing I am simply going from left to right,taking one part of string at a time and using the distances of pulleys in some way or the other to calculate the length of that part of string.

Further note that y and p are constant - fixed pulleys.

Further you may differentiate these to find velocities and accelerations of pulleys.

If you are not familiar with these problems,then try with simple problems first.

Comment: Sir I am familiar with it the method used for solving. I am confused with this problem

Comment: @Rajakr Think from my perspective. I understand that you find it confusing but I do not know what exactly do you find it confusing about it?